# How to force function to evaluate queryset every time it is called

Tags: mysql, django, pythonanywhere

I'm creating a social media site in django, in which each user can have multiple accounts, each with their own posts, friends etc. In order to determine which account to use when loading templates, I have defined this function:

```
def get_active_account(request):
    for account in Account.objects.filter(user=request.user):
        if account.active:
            return account
```

Most views will then call `get_active_account` when they need to evaluate the currently active account. Now, the problem arises when changing the active account. In the view:

```
def set_active(request, pk):
    account = get_object_or_404(Account, pk=pk)
    account.set_active()
    return redirect('/')
```

In the Account model:

```
def set_active(self):
    for account in Account.objects.filter(user=self.user):
        account.active = False
        account.save()
    self.active = True
    self.save()
```

This appears to do nothing; anything referencing the active account will still show the previously active account, and trying to create a post etc. will do it under the old account. After refreshing, however, everything is as it should be. From what I've read, this is a problem with the `get_active_account` function evaluating the queryset once and then returning a cached version when it is called later (although this may be a totally incorrect assumption). How do I fix the problem, and have everything work without needing a browser refresh?

Comment: Since your `set_active` view redirects immediately, and all the querysets you have shown are inside methods, I don't think you have shown anything that would be caching the queryset.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but your `get_active_account` method should just do ` Account.objects.filter(user=request.user, active=True).first()`. But as Alasdair says, nothing here would be caching anything.